# translate.js with select instead of a button

Tags: jquery, internationalization

I am using [translate.js](http://www.openxrest.com/translatejs/) but instead a button (the example in the page) I am trying without success to use a `select` to change between language options.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tg5okdz6/

```
<select name="Language" class="selectpicker lang_selector" data-style="btn-primary" data-width="150px" title='Select the Language'>
    <option value="en" class="trn" data-value="en">English (EN)</option>
    <option value="pt" class="trn" data-value="pt" selected>Português (PT)</option>
</select>
```

Couldn't get the translate.js working in jsfiddle because it doesn't has a https cdn.

Thanks for any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

I test it on chrome and firefox and it works fine. I add in the ende of the script remove option because firefox will ignore default select after refresh.

```
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <p><strong><span class="trn">Step</span> </strong>: <span class="trn" data-trn-key="step">try it</span></p>
        <select name="Language" class="selectpicker lang_selector" data-style="btn-primary" data-width="150px" title='Select the Language'>
            <option value="en" class="trn" data-value="en" selected="selected">English (EN)</option>
            <option value="pt" class="trn" data-value="pt">Português (PT)</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
</div>


<script>
$(function() {

    var t = {
        step: {
            en: "try it",
            pt: "experimentar"
        }
    };
    var _t = $('body').translate({lang: "en", t: t});
    var str = _t.g("translate");
    console.log(str);


    $(".lang_selector").change(function(ev) {
        var lang = $(this).find('option:selected').attr("data-value");
        _t.lang(lang);

        console.log(lang);
        ev.preventDefault();
    });

    $(window).unload(function() {
        $('select option').remove();
    });

});

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, but I couldn't get this to work with your code.

Comment: I tried with the actual code, but it doesn't seens to work.